# Group_concat(distinct) for empty strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Yesterday I posted a question on group_concat. I understood my problem.

I have a table( with 2 empty strings):

```
 Column1


    C
    D
    D
```

I use group_concat(distinct(column1)) and output is:

```
, C, D
```

But I want

```
,  , C, D
```

Because I need Distinct only for letters and not for empty srtings. 
Any ideas?

Comment: It's odd because I've never yet needed group_concat for anything. Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: i need group_concat for anything because after, in my code php, i will use explode() to trasform my string in array. And i need to get all elements (also empty strings) to compare my new array with others

Comment: See. If you skip the group_concat then you can skip the explode. Win-win

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand (my english is very bad and i'm new in SQL and PHP). I can't skip the group_concat (i think) because i need the values in ona row (,  , C, D). And my array with explode will be:
[0]-->""
[1]-->""
[2]-->C
[3]-->D

And i need this to compare with others array

Comment: Thanks, with your advice, i solved my problem. i skipped group_concat, and i used a group by column1. Then i saved all values of column in array in my php file.

Comment: You now have no aggregating functions, so you don't need a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put where clause to remove  the vlues i assume this is Sql server so u can use

```
WHERE TRIM(column_name) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First select all distinct values which are not empty and union it all with empty values. Use this as a sub-query and do `group_concat`.

**Query**

```
select group_concat(t.`col_1` order by t.`col_1`) from(
  select distinct `col_1` from `your_table_name`
  where trim(`col_1`) <> ''
  union all
  select `col_1` from `your_table_name`
  where trim(`col_1`) = ''
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
 group_concat(distinct trim(column1) separator ', ')
```